# Which pattern was matched among those that I passed through a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I am using regexp with `pyhton` and the library `re`. The regular expression I am passing contains many possible variations of a string, such as:

```
myRExp = ("aaaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|ddddd")
```

This is what I am doing to match the full regular expression

```
# read a file with two columns
df = pd.read_csv('a_file.csv')
# get second column and create a unique regular expression
myRExp = "|".join(df[df.columns[1]])
# now test if line contains myRExp
if re.match(myRExp, line):
  # get the actual matching pattern and do something with it
```

What I need to do is to know which substring from myRExp was actually matching the line, i.e. which one between "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc" or "ddddd", matched?

**EDIT**:

Let's go with the example. This is my regular expression:

```
>>> linE = 'zzzzbbdbbxxx'
>>> myRExp = "(aa[a|b]a)|(bb[c|d]bb)|(ccc[d|c]c)"
```

by `re.match()` I can now match it and get this output (note that I am using search to make my point here):

```
# do we have a match? (yes)
>>> matched = re.search(myRExp, linE)
# show groups: I partially care
>>> matched.groups(0)
(0, 'bbdbb', 0)
```

At this point, what I need is the index of the regular expression that matched: the match was (bb[c|d]bb), then the output should be 2, i.e. the index of that regular expression group in myRExp:

```
index of matched.groups(0) in myRExp
```

Is there any way of obtaining the index?

Comment: Put each boolean into its own capture group and use a callback so that you know whether `\1`, `\2`, `\3`, etc... was captured.

Comment: @alexis If OP has a follow up question, it is not a reason to reopen an evident duplicate. Please consider re-closing this evident duplicate post.

Comment: I think that was the OP's question from the start: "which substring from myRExp was actually matching the line". They just didn't know to describe it unambiguously...

Comment: @gabt, you were getting 1s (also the 0s) because `m.groups()` does not require an argument; if you pass one, it is used instead of None.

Comment: @alexis ok, great, that is clear!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew should I rollback to the edit that was explaining the issue? since none of the duplicated questions answer my actual question while here the answer is finally found.

Comment: @gabt Ok, I see your point, please do.

Comment: @alexis I removed the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the ["match object"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) returned by the regex call, and you can examine it:

```
m = re.match(myRExp, line)
if m:
    print("Matched", m.group(0))
```

This will show you the part of your string that matched, which in this case is the simplest way to get what you are after.

If your regex contains groups and you want to know exactly which of the groups matched, use `m.groups()` instead:

```
>>> probe = "(orange)|(or)|(or.*)"
>>> m = re.match(probe, 'order')
>>> m.groups()
(None, 'or', None)
```

There should only be one value that is not None, so you can take its index and look up the regex in your list of regex substrings. Here's one way to find the index with a one-liner:

```
>>> match_index = list(map(bool, m.groups())).index(True)
```

Comment: What if the regex is `\d{3}|\d{4}` and OP needs to know which one was activated. I would advise against getting hung up on the simplicity of their example.

Comment: That's why I linked to the documentation, @MonkeyZeus.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus what does it means that the regex can be `\d{3}\d{4}`?

Comment: @alexis: what if my regex contains subregex such as `myRExp = ("a[a|b]aaa|b[b|c]bbb|cc[c|d]cc|dd[d|e]dd")`. is there a way to know which version of the sub-regex matched by getting its index?

Comment: Yes, sure: Use parentheses for your components as @MonkeyZeus suggested, then check `m.groups()` (a tuple of all the matched subgroups) to see which index contains a match.

Comment: @alexis that is indeed what I was looking for. I wasn't able to cast that `m.groups()`. I guess the trick is done by the function map, right?

Comment: you don't especially need to cast, because `None` is false and non-empty strings are true. But it makes it possible to use `.index(True)` to get the position. Examine `list(map(bool, m.groups()))` to see it sees.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, that you can use [this website](https://regex101.com/)
There you can tinker and adapt your regular expressions and get visual feedback what is matched, when providing test strings. Also the syntax is documented for the rare case you forget some commands ;)